# Formatting JavaScript date

Tags: javascript

I have a string representing a date in the following format :

```
Jun 29, 2019 12:00:00 AM
```

I would like to format this date such as follows:

```
2019-06-29
```

Is there any way of doing this without using any external libraries?

I tried the following and it works fine in Chrome but not in Edge:

```
var stringDate = 'Jun 29, 2019 12:00:00 AM';
var date = new Date(stringDate).toISOString().slice(0,10);
```

Comment: Can you explain what "Doesn't work" in Edge? I just tested this in Edge and it seems fine. Not disputing, it would just give a better idea of what browser shortcomings would need to be accounted for when providing a solution.

Comment: I deleted my comment after @TylerRoper pointed out you didn't want an external library, but as he says it might be useful anyway.  The library is [datejs](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs)

Comment: You should use a library when working with dates, especially when you want to support EDGE and IE11. Look at the support of date formates http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html

Answer (score 2):

Using an external lib like https://momentjs.com/ is of course the easiest option.

But if the dates are always in the format you say, maybe a little bit of regex and javascript might be all you need.

eg.

```js
var resplitdate = /^(\w{3}) (\w{1,2}), (\w{4})/;
var months = 'Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec'.split(",");

function pz(s, size) {
 var r = s.toString();
 while (r.length < size) r = '0' + r;
 return r;
}

function convertDate(d) {
  var splits = resplitdate.exec(d);
  return splits[3] + '-' + 
    pz(months.indexOf(splits[1]) + 1, 2) + "-" +
    pz(splits[2], 2);
}


var stringDate = 'Jun 29, 2019 12:00:00 AM';
console.log(stringDate, " = ", convertDate(stringDate));
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `getFullYear()`, `getDay()` and `getDate()` to get the values. You can then use `padStart()` to pad the beginning of each item with zeros.

```js
var date = new Date('Jun 29, 2019 12:00:00 AM');

console.log(`${date.getFullYear()}-${String(date.getDay()).padStart(2, '0')}-${String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0')}`)
```

Comment: Note that this will not work in many cases, such as if your locale is something where the sixth month is not shortened as "Jun", ie. many foreign languages.

Comment: Passing a non ISO string into the date constructor is not useful. You can get different results in every environment.

Answer (score -2):

A simple way to format the date using javascript(only) could be as follows -

```
var stringDate = 'Jun 29, 2019 12:00:00 AM';

function appendLeadingZeroes(n){
  if(n <= 9){
    return "0" + n;
  }
  return n
}

let current_datetime = new Date(stringDate);
let formatted_date = current_datetime.getFullYear() + "-" + appendLeadingZeroes(current_datetime.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + appendLeadingZeroes(current_datetime.getDate())
console.log(formatted_date)
```

Comment: Passing a non ISO string into the date constructor is not useful. You can get different results in every environment.